# Please proide SQL Query that return row in which Current SYSDate exist between StartDate and Enddate

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns in a table Start date and EndDate , i want to enter Current date and it should compare current date with start and end date if current date exist between start date or enddate must return that row. i have query but not good result found
select * from Seasons where  CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) between '@startdate' and  '@Endate'

Comment: Are '@startdate' and '@Endate' datetime?, date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM seasons 
WHERE getdate() >= @startdate 
AND getdate() <= @enddate
```

Comment: I try this But this is returning All Records

Comment: Give some example rows from your seasons table, and paste the command as you are running it with the parameters.

Comment: Thank You Chris L, yes your Query is OK i got some little mistake in your query from my side. your query is OK made my problem solve . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   SYSDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the below code works for you.

if both the date (startdate and enddate) should match the current date then use this.

```
 select * from Seasons where  convert(date,startdate) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) and convert(date,Endate) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
```

if any one of the date (startdate or enddate) should match the current date then use this.

```
  select * from Seasons where  convert(date,startdate) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) or convert(date,Endate) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
```